# ol3-cesium can't see Globe

Tags: openlayers, cesium

I downloaded release ol3-cesium on my computer from https://github.com/openlayers/ol3-cesium/releases/ and when I open examples from the folder it doesn't show 3D globe or vector data. When I open same examples from http://openlayers.org/ol3-cesium/examples/ it's work properly. Also I try to load vector data and I can't see anything.

Comment: When you say "open examples from folder", do you mean directly, or are you doing the `make serve` step and connecting to localhost:4000?

Answer (score 1):

On my linux I download [ol3-cesium-v1.16.zip](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3-cesium/releases/download/v1.16/ol3-cesium-v1.16.zip), unpack archive, run http server from the ol3-cesium-v1.16 directory:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

next I opened URL http://localhost:8000/examples/ and had seen worked examples.

Try to place unpacked files on web server.